# Java ImageIO.read() returning null

Tags: java, windows, nullpointerexception, javax.imageio

I want to read Images (`.png` files) in my project, and I want this to work in a runnable `.jar` file too. So I wrote this little piece of code:

```
try {
    InputStream in;
    in = Loader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("buttons.png");

    System.out.println(in.read() + ", Reader: " + in);          

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);

    System.out.println(img.getHeight());

    in.close(); 
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
137, Reader: java.io.BufferedInputStream@15db9742
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.Loader.load(Loader.java:21)
    at test.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:6)
```

My `MainTest` does nothing but running this code, so I won't include it here.

I already tested if the `InputStream` is `null` as you may have noticed. As it obviously isn't the path to my file has to be right. My question is: Why is `ImageIO.read()` returning `null`?

Comment: Check that `buttons.png` is at the root directory of the class path of Loader. Case-sensitive, Inspect the .jar file with 7zip, WinZip or the like.

Comment: getResource(AsStream) will return null when the resource can't be found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is the line that reads from `in` before passing it to `ImageIO.read(..)` (you are reading the first byte):

```
System.out.println(in.read() + ", Reader: " + in);
```

When you read a byte from the stream, this byte is effectively "consumed" and will not be read again, thus `ImageIO` will never see this byte, causing the file format (PNG) to not be recognized. In this case, `ImageIO.read(..)` will return `null`.

Just remove that line, and your code should work fine.

The file seems to be present as `in` is not `null`. And the value `137` that you print, is actually the first byte of the [PNG signature](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Structure.html), meaning the file is fine and properly included in your JAR.

---

If you really need to peek into the bytes in the stream before passing to `ImageIO`, you could do something like:

```
in.mark(256); // allows you to read up to 256 bytes before calling reset()
System.out.println(in.read() + ", Reader: " + in); // or whatever you like to do
in.reset(); // "rewind" to beginning of stream (previous mark)
```

Just be careful, as not all streams supports `mark()/reset()` methods (you can test, using the `boolean markSupported()` method).

Comment: Youre absolutely right. I worked that one out now too  :D. But thank you very much for your help and the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

As you already read on the `InputStream` before the call to `ImageIO.read`, it may happens that the function is unable to decode the image correctly. Remove the call to `in.read()`, and test the results of the calls.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream-

`ImageIO.read(...)` may return null if it's unable to decode the image. Check for that case as well.